# Replace datagridviewtextcolumn to datagridviewcombo

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Hello sir i have one requirement but i am stuck how to do

i have datagridview like this

---

> **|Order NO |Values |**
>
> |order no value | values depends on order no |

what i am trying to do is on bases of order no selected i want to bind second combo named `values`

NOTE  :- i am binding it after giving datasource to it

so my code will looks like this

```
datagridview.datasource = datatable
```

and after that i am binding combobox but its not working can anyone have a good hand on it i have not idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
Dim comboBoxColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
comboBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Location"
comboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Location"
comboBoxColumn.DataSource = dtLocations

comboBoxColumn.ValueMember = dtLocations.Columns(0).ColumnName

comboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = dtLocations.Columns(1).ColumnName

dgvPickList.Columns.RemoveAt(1)

dgvPickList.Columns.Insert(1, comboBoxColumn)
```

Comment: I think your code is right but at which event i should put this that's the major confusion

Comment: is orderno is available every time?

Comment: when its blank then nothing will be binded

Comment: Ok then in which event should i bind it?